# Input Box Will Not Work in AngularStrap Select Custom Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I created a custom template for the AngularStrap Select directive but I am unable to type inside of the textbox that I have added to the template for some reason.  I would like to use this textbox to filter the list items.

**Custom HTML Template (/dist/select.html)**

The only thing that I added here from the default template was another `<li>` element that includes the textbox.  Said another way, I basically copy & pasted the default template and added the `<li>` and `<input>` elements.

```
<ul tabindex="-1" class="select dropdown-menu" ng-show="$isVisible()" role="select">
    <li>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="iconFilter" />
    </li>
    <li ng-if="$showAllNoneButtons">
        <div class="btn-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 5px">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="$selectAll()">All</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="$selectNone()">None</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="match in $matches" ng-class="{active: $isActive($index)}">
        <a style="cursor: default;" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="$select($index, $event)">
            <i class="{{$iconCheckmark}} pull-right" ng-if="$isMultiple && $isActive($index)"></i>
            <span ng-bind="match.label"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**HTML**

This is the actual HTML that includes the call to the bs-select directive.

```
<button ng-if="path() === '/contacts/people'"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
    ng-model="selectedIcon"
    data-html="1"
    data-multiple="1"
    data-template="/dist/select.html"
    ng-options="icon.value as icon.label for icon in getIcons()"
    bs-select>
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```